# Why is "1" not a valid variable? Why is there not a function plotted in the Plot function?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, warning-messages

**This is my code for playing this kind of stuff**

```
    A = {1, 1};
    B = {0, -1};
    c = {x, 0};
    l1 = EuclideanDistance[A, c];
    l2 = EuclideanDistance[c, B];
    f[x_] := l1/1 + l2/2;
    D[f[x], x]
    g[x_] := D[f[x], x]
    g[1]
    Plot[g[x], {x, -20, 20}, PlotRange -> 20 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
    PlotStyle -> Red, AspectRatio -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 400]
```

---

To clarify, there seem to be three or four questions, some of which are in the title, some to be inferred from comments or evaluating the code:

1. Why are `Abs'[1 - x]` and `Abs'[x]` left unevaluated in the output of `D[f[x], x]`?
2. Why does `g[1]` result in an error "`General::ivar` 1 is not a valid variable"?
3. Why does `Plot[...]` generate similar `General::ivar` errors?
4. Why does the `Plot` comes up empty when only the previous two problems are fixed? (It came up blank originally because of the problem with `D[...]`.)

Comment: @MichaelE2, but your link hasn't answered the question about No  `Plot` in the function

Comment: @MichaelE2, Thank u for your answer first, this link you put here hasn't answered the Plot problem in Abs.

Comment: Hi, I edited the questions you seemed to have about your code into the body of your post to make clear what all the questions are. I think the linked questions address each one, and it's nice to have the Q&A's linked because it helps others searching for answers to the same or similar problem. -- Also, here's another workaround: `f[x_] = Block[{Abs = RealAbs}, l1/1 + l2/2]` together with Carl's suggestion of `g = f'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several things going on here. First, both `l1` and `l2` use [`Abs`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Abs):

```
l1
l2
```

> Sqrt[1 + Abs[1 - x]^2]
>
> Sqrt[1 + Abs[x]^2]

Mathematica will not compute the derivative of [`Abs`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Abs) because it is not analytic as a complex function. One possibility is to use [`ComplexExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand) to eliminate the [`Abs`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Abs):

```
m1 = ComplexExpand @ l1
m2 = ComplexExpand @ l2
```

> Sqrt[1 + (1 - x)^2]
>
> Sqrt[1 + x^2]

Next, your definition of `f` is problematic because the RHS does not contain an explicit `x` variable. It is better to use either:

```
f[x_] = m1/2 + m2/2
```

or:

```
f[x_] := Evaluate[m1/2 + m2/2]
```

so that the RHS is evaluated when defining `f`. Finally, when you define:

```
g[x_] := D[f[x], x]
```

and evaluate `g[1]`, Mathematica will try to evaluate:

```
D[f[1], 1]
```

which is why you get your message. It is much better to use:

```
g = f'
```

instead to define a derivative function. So:

```
Clear[f, g];

f[x_] = m1/2 + m2/2;
g = f';
Plot[g[x], {x, -20, 20}]
```

[image]

Comment: Carl Woll, thank you for your answer. What remained unanswered in this question was about how to add `g[1]` in this code. How are you gonna solve this?

Comment: @kile Simply use `g[1]`. Notice `g[x_]=……` isn't the only way for defining a function, and in this case the function relationship `g` is defined by `g=f'`.